# From what url snaps are downloaded?

Tags: snap, url

I am facing slow speed when downloading snaps.

I have to tell my ISP provider the url from where snaps are downloaded.

My ISP provides 5 mbps connection but I am just getting 1 mbps:

[image]

Comment: ...that's actually 0.1mbps on the screenshot. Is it only when downloading snaps? Have you tried a speedtest?

Comment: Yes. There are two results. From chrome http://www.speedtest.net/result/7475126645 and from firefox http://www.speedtest.net/result/7475126645

Comment: Hello @K7AAY it's not just Keepassxc. Here is the same for brave, which I am downloading right now. https://imgur.com/K3wXCx8 . I thought all snaps are from same server.

Comment: 'Snaps' are files accessed by https:// so it depends on which snap you are loading. and there's no way to tell where they are. They can be on their own servers, even on a local LAN, as well as on Canonical's servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two hosts it will hit are `api.snapcraft.io` and `dashboard.snapcraft.io`. However the snaps are delivered via a content delivery network (two in fact, I believe) so it's not as simple as one host.

If you'd like to help debug speed issues when downloading snaps, here's some steps you can try to get more information.

1. Enable debugging in snapd.

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl edit snapd.service

   [Service]
   Environment=SNAPD_DEBUG=1 SNAPD_DEBUG_HTTP=7
   ```
2. Restart snapd

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl restart snapd.service
   ```
3. Install a large snap such as libreoffice or vscode

   ```
   $ sudo snap install libreoffice
   ```
4. Then inspecting the logs using

   ```
   $ journalctl -xeu snapd
   ```

I'd recommend starting a thread on the [snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/) in the [store](https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/store) category, where the store admins and developers hang out. They're the only ones who can debug this, honestly.